# NullPointerException, can't find reason even after research

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm having bad times with creating typical card/deck class in java. I've read some similar questions & answers but either they're not relatable/helpful or I can't simply comprehend it yet.
Here's the code

```
public class Cards {
    boolean isAvailable;
    int card_id;
    static final int AC = 32;
    public Cards [] deck = new Cards[AC];

    public void set () {
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < AC; i++) {
            if(a == 4) a = 0;
            deck[i].isAvailable = true;     // <---------
            deck[i].card_id = i + (a * 101);    // <---------
            a++;
        }   
    }
    public void read () {
        for (int i = 0; i < AC; i++) 
        System.out.println(deck[i].isAvailable + "  " + deck[i].card_id);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Cards c = new Cards();
        c.set();
        c.read();       
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at Cards.set(Cards.java:13)
>   at Cards.main(Cards.java:24)

1.
I've read about similar issues and found that problem can be in initialization of an array and I've tried to do the same with my prog but it went bad anyway.

I marked 13th and 14th lines because they are being pointed (when i comment 13th line just for check, pointer sets to the next line).

2.
Next part of help I would like to get from you is:
Even though there is main (for training purposes), I see other class using this class (which just creates deck) so I guess I won't be needing main... Is everything well set besides probs in first point?

Comment: *Where* have you "tried to do the same" in terms of array initialization? I don't see anywhere that you set `deck[i]` to a value...

Comment: When you have a bug in your code, I suggest using your debugger. That's what it is for.

Comment: I suggest you separate `Card` as a single card, from `Cards` as a collection of cards. Currently each Cards has an array of 52 Cards inside it which doesn't make sense (especially as each of those Cards will have 52 Cards etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very simple:

```
public Cards [] deck = new Cards[AC];
```

creates an **empty** array with AC number of slots for Cards objects.

Now you have to put a **non-null** Cards object into each slot!

But thing is: actually your **abstraction** is broken.

You wrote code that seems to take **one** card to be the same as a **card set** - by adding that **array** of Cards into your Cards class! And that makes it actually *hard* to **fix** your current code. As the "normal" way to fix this would be to add a constructor like

```
public Cards() {
  deck = new Cards[AC];
  for (int i=0; i<deck.length;i++) {
    deck[i] = new Cards();
}
```

If you try that ... you **immediately** run into an endless recursion (creating **one** new Cards would result in creating AC new Cards (to fill the array); causing a stackoverflow very soon.

Thus the real answer goes somewhere along these lines:

```
public class Card {
  ... a class that represents a SINGLE card in your game
```

and then

```
public card GameOfCards {
  ... a class that (for example!) uses an array to hold n objects of class Card!
```

Finally, as Peter is indicating in his comment: you should learn to use *debugging means* to work on such problems yourself. One good way: before using any data structure, iterate it and print out its content. Or even better, learn how to use a debugger, and walk through your code step by step! As you should please understand: this is very **basic** stuff; that you *normally* should not bring forward here.

Comment: Using the debugger would quickly demonstrate this +1

Comment: @PeterLawrey I was more focused on improving the "beyond the question" quality of my answer; but of course, you are correct about the "how he should be debugging this" ;-)

Comment: I agree with the separation of Cards vs one Card. Sorry I can't vote twice. I wouldn't call it a Set as a Deck is usually an ordered set like a LinkedHashSet would be, but most Sets are not.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I was struggling with that name too. Just changed it, hope you like the new name ;-) ... and no need to apologize. You know, people that can upvote twice ... would be those having an upvoter-sockpuppet around. And we are all reasonable grown-ups. so we don't have those. But of course, if you like upvoting my stuff, I got 1185 answers by now; and I am pretty sure that many high-quality answers in that set have not been upvoted by you yet ;-)

Comment: Sure does. Where I was just hoping you would accidentally upvote some of my late *questions*, as I think I had difficulties communicating the greatness of their quality ... killing my *streak* of positive answer score ...

Comment: Thank you all for respond. Solution with one card scheme is great and simple and description of why I failed also did much good.
I really tried and failed completely to seek solution in similar topics, and as a super new to java/eclipse didn't even think of debugger as a full help provider. I didn't realize I was doing such mess with that array!